# Jquery or Javascript that display content based on the date HELP

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery or JavaScript  that displays content based on specifics date period

so we have like 3 dates
12/3/2010
12/11/2010
12/20/2010

and
Div Contents

Content 1 should be displaying from 12/3 to 12/11
Content 2 should be display from 12/11 to 12/20
and Content 3 should be displaying from 12/20 there after

Comment: where's your data? Do you get it as JSON from server or is it part of some element (ie. table)? I suppose your data has a date part...

Comment: the data is going to be hard coded inside the divs

Comment: Where dates are stored? What kind of structure?

Comment: This question is far too vague to give any constructive help.

Comment: It's quite a bad idea to do this in JavaScript, you'll be at the mercy of users who have their PC clock set incorrectly. It would be much better to serve up the appropriate div based on the server's clock, not serve up all three and let JavaScript sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

First, like others said this whole thing is bad idea as you're depending on the client machine date/time and correct approach would be doing that in server side.

Anyway, guess you have your reasons so here is jQuery solution.

Have such HTML:

```
<div class="DateDiv"><span class="DateRange">1/1/2010 to 1/1/2011</span>I'll be visible during 2010</div>
<div class="DateDiv"><span class="DateRange">1/1/2011 to 1/1/2012</span>I'll be visible during 2011</div>
<div class="DateDiv"><span class="DateRange">1/1/2012 to 1/1/2013</span>I'll be visible during 2012</div>
```

Put the date range inside a span inside each div with the class "DateRange".

Next, have such CSS to have them initially hidden:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .DateRange, .DateDiv { display: none; }
</style>
```

And finally, this script: (jQuery)

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(function() {
    $(".DateDiv").each(function(index) {
        var sRange = $(this).find(".DateRange").html();
        var arrTemp = sRange.split(" to ");
        var dtFrom = new Date(arrTemp[0]);
        var dtTo = new Date(arrTemp[1]);
        var dtNow = new Date();
        if (dtNow >= dtFrom && dtNow <= dtTo)
            $(this).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Test case is available here feel free to mess around with it: http://jsfiddle.net/2BHLd/

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple code. It should work as you want (if I have understood you well).
I know, there's no doctype in my HTML and there are some missing tags. The HTML I've provided is just a kind of template.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var date=new Date();
var year=date.getFullYear();
var month=date.getMonth();
var day=date.getDate(); // fixed
function SetDivContent() {
    var div=document.getElementById('date_dependent');
    if (year==2010 && month==11) { // fixed (the JavaScript months order is 0-11, not 1-12)
        if (day>=3 && day<11) { // the following content will be displayed 12/03/2010, 12/04/2010, [...], 12/09/2010, 12/10/2010
            div.innerHTML='content 1';
        }
        else if (day==11 || day==12) { // this one will be displayed 12/11/2010 and 12/12/2010
            div.innerHTML='content 2';
        }
        else if (day>12) { // this one - 12/13/2010 and later, until the end of December
            div.innerHTML='content 3';
        }
    }
    else if (year==2011 && month>=0) div.innerHTML='content 3'; // OPTIONAL - just to ensure that content 3 is displayed even after December.
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="SetDivContent()">
<div id="date_dependent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that if you want to hide some data from users if the specified date hasn't come yet, you should better use something server-side for security reasons. Otherwise, any user may just read the page's source. Also remember that the following code is executed when the body is loaded, i.e. each time a user refreshes the page.
**EDIT:** Warning: there were two bad lines (I've made a mistake before). Anyway, I've fixed them. The current code works, I've tested it.

Comment: Thanks, but i was looking for the hide/show events..and the content being hidden in the body first...instead of doing a innerHTML

Comment: Thanks it works. was planning on dropping flash content in the InnerHTML...i dont think it may work..but going to test it out now.

Comment: I've added a new line, marked as "OPTIONAL". You can add it to your code if you want the content 3 to be displayed even in 2011.

Comment: i wanted  to write it something like this
var now = new Date();

var Christmas = new Date("December 25, 2010");


if(now > Christmas) // today is after Christmas
{
     // an id of a div that holds your images?
     $('#div').show();
     
}



The Content needs to go in the body instead of the script..any ideas?

is there anyway we can write is like how it is currently but not having the html part in the InnerHTML??

Comment: What's wrong with `innerHTML`? Unless you want to wrestle `appendChild` and all of those other fun functions, I see no reason to refuse to use `innerHTML`...